# Gnuplot and Spherical/Cylindrical plotting

Tags: plot, gnuplot, cylindrical, spherical-coordinate

I have some questions with plotting in 3D withe `Gnuplot`
I need to plot some data (from files) in spherical coordinates.
My data are organized as following,

```
azimuth   zenith    intensity  

1    2    0.256e-2  
2    2    0.156e-2  
3    3    ...
```

I use:

```
splot "data.out" using 1:2:3
```

but the third column is used as a radius...so if I want to compare 2 different set of datas, with different intensity, my plot become unreadable

is there a way to fix the radius to a specific value instead of using the third column as radius?

Sorry for the long post (-:  (and the mistakes...I'm not a native English speaker)
Thanks a lot for your help
Hyppie-Psi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I understand what you are looking for but you can
do some operation on the `using 1:2:3` part. For instance, if you write

```
splot "data.out" using 1:2:(12.3)
```

you will have the `z` coordinate of `12.3` for all your `x` and `y` points. You
can also do more complicated operations, like

```
splot "data.out" using 1:2:($3*$3)
```

where you square the third column of your data file. You can also for instance
go in spherical coordinate by doing:

```
splot "data.out" using ($3*cos($1)*cos($2)):($3*sin($1)*cos($2)):($3*sin($2))
```

which, if I understood your question, is equivalent to simply

```
set mapping spherical
splot "data.out" using 1:2:3
```

With these informations, you should be able to perform any operation you like on your third column data to display in a way you like.